# session cookies empty after getting response from flask

Tags: python, rest, flask, python-requests

I have a server written in flask and flask-socketio and a command line client written using request. When i try getting a login request from the server like this:

```
...
session = requests.Session()
url = BASE_URL + '/auth/login'
data = {'username': username, 'password': password}
response = session.post(url, json=data)
print(response.text)
print(response.cookies.get_dict())
...
```

I get this output:

```
ok
{'session': 'eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxfQ.ZKBsnA.JVmRnEZbBvlCUpZFWWQgHmjJ0kY'}
```

Here is how my login handler looks:

```
@bp.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.json['username']
        password = request.json['password']

        if not username:
            return 'Username is required.', 400
        elif not password:
            return  'Password is required.', 400
        else:
            user = db.get_user(username)
            if user is None:
                return 'Incorrect username.', 400
            elif not db.verify_password(username, password):
                return 'Incorrect password.', 400
            else:
                session.clear()
                session['user_id'] = user['id']

                return 'ok', 200
    else:
        return 'Method not allowed.', 405
```

I expected the response cookie to contain the user_id field but it doesn't.

- How do I fix this?
- How do I keep a persistent session between the client and the server so that it doesn't keep resetting the session?

Comment: It depends on how you have your sessions configured.  If you have a backing store, then the cookie ONLY contains a session ID.  The session data is stored in a database on the server that is indexed by the session ID.  That's a huge bandwidth savings.  After all, the client doesn't need to know what session data the server is storing.